Ensuring Equivalence in Python Functions: Understanding Implementation Impacts
In defining function equivalence, several factors come into play:

Producing equivalent results
Sharing the same (non-)termination behavior
Mutating (non-local) memory similarly
Maintaining identical input/output and raising the same exceptions

Moreover, renaming arguments without altering their order should not affect equivalence, unless they refer to something else within the function body.
def g(x: bool) -> bool: 
    return True

# Functions f and f2 are equivalent

def f(x: bool) -> bool:
    return x and g(x)

def f2(x: bool) -> bool:
    if x:
        return g(x)
    else:
        return False

# Functions f3 and f4 are not equivalent

def f3(x: bool) -> bool:
    return x and g(x)

def f4(x: bool) -> bool:
    if g(x):
        return x
    else:
        return False

Consider the equivalence between f and f2: in both functions, g(x) is invoked only when x is True, adhering to the same rule. Also, f3 and f4 reveal a distinct implementation. In f3, g(x) remains uncalled if x is False, whereas in f4, g(x) is invoked regardless of the value of x.
I'm curious as to why f3 and f4 are considered non-equivalent. Despite having identical output for all potential inputs, is their lack of equivalence only due to implementation differences?

Who says that f3 and f4 are non-equivalent? And it seems you have already identified an important difference between them.

f3 ad f4 are equivalent? can you please elaborate.

The execution isn't equivalent due to the short-circuiting you've identified, even if the results are (given the g() you have).

f and f2 are only equivalent if you enforce the type annotations, f('') returns something else than f2('').

I didn't mean to say that f3 and f4 are equivalent, I was curious why you think they were non-equivalent and giving a reason for it, and at the same time were wondering why this is so.

So this means that somehow evaluation order will take precedence in calling those two "equal" before the output? So something like "It does not matter that the output is the same for every single input those two are not equivalent because of the evaluation order"?

If this is your definition of equivalence then yes.

@mkrieger1 So I thought the are not equivalent because f3 is using syntactic sugar , and the right side is executed only if the left side is true. Now inside f4 g(x) is always executed. So what threw me off is both functions will return the same output and the evaluation order is not going to matter now.

In an ideal world,

All functions would be pure.
The and operator is defined to be commutative, meaning (a and b) == (b and a).

The above conditions justifies the short-circuiting in and's implementation.
This should allow us to consider f3 and f4 as equivalent.
But, Python isn't a pure functional programming language, which means the function g could have non purity / side-affects, like printing to I/O, writing to a database, making an API call etc.
Because of this side-affects, the short-circuiting can yield unexpected results, making f3 and f4 non-equivalent.

So this means that pure functional programming languages cannot have side effects by design (that the programming language itself does not allow it) or just like the programmer would not do it?

A programming language without side effects wouldn't be useful. Since taking user input or showing output in any form or way is an impure/side-effect operation.
So yeah, pure functional programming languages, take Haskell for example, does let you to write impure functions. But you'll explicitly have to tell the compiler that a given function is impure. If not, the compiler assumes purity and refuses to compile if you have impure expressions inside the function.
